# Program crashes when the object reaches the ends of y-axis

Tags: c++

```
void Rover::move(Mars& mars)
{   
    if (heading=='^' && y-1 >= 0){
        mars.setObject(x,y,' ');
        y-=1;
        mars.setObject(x,y,'^');
    }
    if (heading=='>' && x+1 < mars.getDimX()){
        mars.setObject(x,y,' ');
        x+=1;
        mars.setObject(x,y,'>');
    }
    if(heading=='<' && x-1 >= 0){
        mars.setObject(x,y,' ');
        x-=1;
        mars.setObject(x,y,'<');
    }
    if(heading=='v' && y+1 < mars.getDimY()){
        mars.setObject(x,y,' ');
        y+=1;
        mars.setObject(x,y,'v');
    }
    Explore(mars);
}
```

Above is the block of code that dictates the movements of Rover in a 2D array. The x-axis is constructed from left to right and the y-axis is constructed from top to bottom.

The movements along the x-axis are completely fine, such that in a 10x10 map, the Rover can reach both ends of the x-axis and further movements will not cause it to go out of the map.

[Rover reaches the end of x-axis just fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97q03.png)

However, when it comes to the y-axis, the program crashes whenever I move to either end of the axis. For example, in a 10x10 map, when I move it from y=9 to y=10, the program straight out crashes.

[Rover cannot move from 9 to 10.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOiDa.png)
[No error messages, program straight away terminates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Dxr.png)

I have been fondling around with it for the entire day now, and I am really out of clues. If the logic works for the x-axis, why would it not work for the y-axis?

Unfortunately it might be too long a code to even include a minimal reproducible sample as the entire program has >700 lines of codes.

Any ideas would be really neat. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the type of `x`?  Is it by chance `unsigned`?  (`x-1` might not be the value you think it is when `x` is 0)

Comment: *I have been fondling around with it for the entire day now* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset.  If you haven't done that, then from what you are describing, using a debugger should have taken minutes to find the issue.

Comment: "_in a 10x10 map, when I move it from y=9 to y=10, the program straight out crashes_" - Do you perhaps have an array of `[10][10]` and you try to use `[10][...]` (which is out of bounds)?

Comment: if there is no error code...maybe your programm just reaches some condition and ends? It dosen't seem to me that error is within the block of code you show..

Comment: _Unfortunately it might be too long a code to even include a minimal reproducible sample as the entire program has >700 lines of codes._  You need to **make** a minimal reproducible sample.  Start eliminating stuff and isolate the issue.

Comment: Looks like the bug is in the code not provided. My guess is that `Mars::setObject` has a bug.

Comment: Do you have a debugger?

Comment: @user253751 As much as I wish to use one, I have no clue how to. Checked various guides online and still have no clue about its configuration. Just started learning programming this semester so everything is still kinda new to me.

Comment: if you're using visual studio, you should just be able to press "start debugging" and it should run your program and pause the program when it crashes, and then there are ways to look at variables, etc

Comment: @kaede1 what is the error you get when the program crashes. Is it segmentation fault?

Comment: ***As much as I wish to use one, I have no clue how to*** The 20 minutes you spend learning how to use your debugger will save you many hours in the long run and make you a better programmer.

Comment: @justaguy The program doesn't give any errors. It just ends,.

Comment: @kaede1 did you consider that your programm just exit because it somehow returned to your main loop and ended maybe make a print statement before the end of the program to see if there is a logic error in your program that does not crash your program but just ends it

Comment: @kaede1 -- *Unfortunately it might be too long a code to even include a minimal reproducible sample as the entire program has >700 lines of codes.* -- I'm sorry, but this statement absolutely *requires* you to know, have, and use the debugger.  There are no excuses at this point for not doing this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think the debugger would find anything wrong since it seems to me that the program exits properly but not when it should do so. That doesn't change that using a debugger is generally a good idea.